# Send Webform fields in ASP using Visual Studio to 3rd Party API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I am creating a webform in Visual Studio and I need to send the data from the form fields to a 3rd party API using POST. I have tried using json to capture the form fields and send the json object, but I am not able to do so. I get the error, "Authorization has been denied for this request.". I am new to ASP and json.This is a sample of my code, not the actual code(unfortunately I cannot provide the exact code). When I run this POST request using an application like Advanced REST Client, I am able to successfully send the request.

My sample code:

```
<form action='https://test' method="post" name="MY Form">
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" /><br />
        <input id="button1" name="button1" type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

JavaScript:
    $('#button1').click(function() {
    formData = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Bearer <token>',
        url: 'https://test',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't really see a question here. Just an error, and no code. Please provide a [MCVE] and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please do not post a giant block of code in the comments. It needs to be in your question (please edit it into there and remove your comment). It needs to satisfy the MCVE requirements I linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

formData = json.stringfy({

```
    'username': $('#username').val(),

    'password': $('#password').val()

};
```